# Creating a function to turn a SQL query into Pandas df

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'd like to create a function that allows the user to input a SQL query and have it converted into a Pandas df.  So far I've tried the following:

```
def dataset():
    raw_sql_query = input("Enter your SQL query: ")
    sql_query = """" " + raw_sql_query + " """" 
sql3 =
sql_query
df = pd.io.sql.read_sql(sql3, cnxn)
df.head()
```

Which yields the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-18-6b10c2bc776f>", line 4
    sql_query = """" " + raw_sql_query + " """"
                                                ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I've also tried a few similar versions of the above code, including:

```
def dataset():
    raw_sql_query = input("Enter your SQL query: ")
    sql_query = """"" + raw_sql_query + """"" 
sql3 =
sql_query 
df = pd.io.sql.read_sql(sql3, cnxn)
df.head()
```

Which led to the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-23-e501c9746878>", line 5
    sql3 =
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is a function like this possible?  If so, how would I go about creating a working function for this action?
All the documentation I've read about functions only includes examples for stuff like printing "Hello World" or basic addition/subtraction/etc - so not very useful.

EDIT:
Using `pandas.read_sql_query` like this:

```
def dataset():
    """This functions allows you to input a SQL query and it will be transformed into a Pandas dataframe"""
    raw_sql_query = input("Enter your SQL query: ")
    sql_query = """"" + raw_sql_query + """"" 
sql3 = sql_query 
df = pd.io.sql.read_sql(sql3, cnxn)
df.head()
```

This doesn't return an error, but also doesn't return the expected results.  It returns nothing.

Comment: Two things. You have serious indentation problems here. You can't just do sql3 = with value on next line. The second thing is, that pandas has built in sql reader https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: Be sure to sanitize and validate such user input as `read_sql` can potentially execute DML commands like `DELETE FROM table` or `DROP table` and return an error since no `SELECT` resultset is returned for a df.

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

I like the flexibility of `sqlalchemy` combined to `pandas.read_sql`. This is the code that I use:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

def bindQuery(query, **params):
    for key, value in params.items():
        key =  f":{key}"
        if isinstance(value, str):
            value = f"'{value}'"
        query = query.replace(key, str(value))
    query = query.replace("\n", " ").replace("\t", " ")
    return query


def readQuery(query, engine, **params):
    query = bindQuery(query, **params)
    return pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

So when I've to run the following `QUERY`

```py
QUERY = """
SELECT count(*) 
FROM table
where id in :ids
"""

ids = (1, 2, 3)

df = readQuery(query=QUERY,
               engine=my_engine,
               ids=ids)
```